# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent softdelete not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, soft-delete

I have a softdelete trait in my model. I've been trying to delete the file in db but is not working. Here's my model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'files';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

My migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

And in my controller, I'm doing it this way.

```
$fileID = explode('/', $img)[1];

$JobImage = JobImage::where('file_id', $fileID)->update(['file_id' => null]); <- I'm updating first the column value of it's relationship to null, which works well.
$file = File::where('id', $fileID)->delete();
```

I don't understand if which part do I lack?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use like this

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('files', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->dropSoftDeletes(); //add this line
    });
}
```

[Follow This link. It is clear picture to you](https://medium.com/@chrissoemma/laravel-5-8-delete-and-soft-delete-practical-examples-b9b71c0a97f)

Comment: @EemJee Follow this link.

Comment: I'm currently using Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `fillable` or `guarded` attribute in your model.
Because `delete` action uses Mass Assignment to stores `deleted_at`

Comment: What columns should I add in the guarded or fillable ?

Comment: you can add `id` column to `guarded`. it's mean you added other columns to `fillable`